# Got " unrecognized selector sent to instance" for a valid value

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I have a `UITableViewCell` as

```
@interface RestaurantTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *restaurantName;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *restaurantImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *ratingImage;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *reviewsCount;
@end
```

I set it properties based on data I receive from server. The code looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RestaurantTableViewCell *restaurantViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RestaurantTableViewCell"];
    NSDictionary *business = self.businesses[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    restaurantViewCell.restaurantName.text = business[@"name"];
    restaurantViewCell.addressLabel.text = business[@"location"][@"address"][0];
    NSObject *reviewCount = business[@"review_count"];
    NSLog(@"review count: %@", (NSString *)reviewCount);
    restaurantViewCell.reviewsCount.text = (NSString *) reviewCount;
    [self fetchImage:restaurantViewCell restaurantImageUrl:[business valueForKeyPath:@"image_url"] imageType:RESTAURANT];
    [self fetchImage:restaurantViewCell restaurantImageUrl:[business valueForKeyPath:@"rating_img_url"] imageType:RATING];

    return restaurantViewCell;
}
```

When I run application, I see logs as

```
2014-06-19 15:38:11.144 yelp[27300:70b] total rows: 20
2014-06-19 15:38:11.146 yelp[27300:70b] review count: 1230
2014-06-19 15:38:11.149 yelp[27300:70b] review count: 1009
2014-06-19 15:38:11.151 yelp[27300:70b] review count: 769
2014-06-19 15:38:11.152 yelp[27300:70b] review count: 266
2014-06-19 15:38:11.153 yelp[27300:70b] review count: 442
2014-06-19 15:38:11.155 yelp[27300:70b] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9266c50
2014-06-19 15:38:11.161 yelp[27300:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9266c50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
```

**Question**

When `reviewCount` is a valid value, why does it fail?

Thanks

Comment: Clearly `reviewCount` is actually an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. You can't simply use a cast to change that.

Comment: `-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector`. Read that until you understand it.

Comment: It's definitely important for developers to understand that error, but Apple really could make it easier. For example, "the message 'length' was sent to the instance of __NSCFNumber at address 0x9266c50, which doesn't understand it". There could be a slightly different form for messages sent to class objects.

Comment: it looks like , Crash due to you are trying to access length of NSNumber, which is not the property of NSNumber.You can add an exception breakpoint and see where is the exact issue. Good idea to try with NSZombieEnabled.

Comment: Analysis: NSNumber does not have length function, so, we need to convert NSCFNumber to NSString. like NSString*myString =[NSNumber stringValue];

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, I realized the mistake.

The following made it wot work

```
[restaurantViewCell.reviewsCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", reviewCount]];
```

Comment: Just do you know, when you format an object with the `%@` specifier, that obtains a string from the object by asking for its `-description`. So, your `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", reviewCount]` is just a clunky and somewhat inefficient way of writing `[reviewCount description]`.